# Making Mob Spawners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I'm trying to make Mob Spawners with WorldEdit. According to their wiki:

> **Mob spawner mob type**
>    The mob spawner mob type can be specified after a pipe symbol (|).
>
> *Example: Setting mob type*
>   `//set mobspawner|Squid`

I've tried this, and it doesn't seem to work, I still get a mob spawner with a pig inside. The pipe symbol (which I can type here fine as `|`) comes up as `¦` in the Minecraft console, is this a problem?

Comment: Are you in multiplayer. There's a glitch in which all spawners look like they have pigs inside.

Comment: No, single player.

Comment: Did you actually wait for something to spawn? At least in multiplayer it is a well-known bug that WorldEdit's mob-spawners show up as pig-spawners that spawn your desired mob but also client-only pigs

Comment: Yup. Set difficulty to hard and removed all torches - nothing spawns at all (no grass).

Comment: The pipe isn't the problem: pipe and "broken pipe" is just a font difference when it's the same input key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WorldEdit you must have Bukkit installed. If so install this [plugin](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/misc-mech-mob-spawner-changer-v0-3-change-what-a-mob-spawner-spawns-1000.26038/)

With this, you'll be able to change the spawn to whatever you like.

**UPDATE**

I've found exactly what you're looking for [here](http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/craftable-mob-spawners-103710/)

You can craft mob spawners with ingredient, you just have to download Mod Loader and put some class in the .minecraft/mods folder. You should find instructions on his page. And yes it's for single player

Comment: For single player?

Answer (score 0):

The first of the other answer given is strange, so I have a solution for Single-player. For Single-player, there is no direct WorldEdit mod, it comes with the [Single-Player Commands](http://bit.ly/spcmod)(or SPC) mod, as well as the [Single-Player Console](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1010003-143132125-single-player-console-updated-6th-november/) if you want to install it for Single-player. For more information on this, as well as installing the mods, visit [SK's wiki](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Installation).